# check if gpg-agent is installed from bash

Tags: bash, scripting, fedora, gnupg

I'm looking for the best way to check if gpg-agent is installed in a a machine.
I need to check from a shell script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to modify the path. Tested with RHEL 6 and 7.

```
if test -x /usr/bin/gpg-agent; then echo installed; else echo not installed; fi
```

Or:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/gpg-agent ]; then echo insatlled; else echo not installed; fi
```

Further Reading: `help test`.